# AVR programming, push button not working

Tags: avr, embedded, programming

I was trying to study AVR programming using an Arduino. I just wanted to blink some LEDs.  At first I succeeded then I tried using a push button for it.  It didn't work out. I tried using a switch debouncing circuit.  It didn't work out.

Please help me find out why is it not working.

The LED is not glowing when I connect the connection to the push button and press it.  It works when it is connected directly to 5V. Please help me out here.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main (void) {

    DDRD &= (0<<DDD5);
    DDRD |= (1<<DDD2) | (1<<DDD3);
    
 if (PIND & (1<<PIND5) )
 {      _delay_ms(500);  
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD2);
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);
 }
else{
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTD &= (0<<PORTD2);
        PORTD &= (0<<PORTD3);
}
}
```

This was without the debounce circuitry:

[image: this was without the debounce circuitry]

It doesn't work in either case:

[image: both case its not working]

Comment: How have you debugged if the pushbutton is the correct way around or correctly inserted and makes a good connection? The code has problems too, but for the purpose of doing what it is supposed to, it will work.

Comment: test the switch ... remove the yellow wire ... move the switch to the resistor where the yellow wire was ... connect the other side of the switch to `+` ... press button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to put this part of the

```
 if (PIND & (1<<PIND5) )
 {      _delay_ms(500);  
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD2);
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);
 }
else{
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTD &= (0<<PORTD2);
        PORTD &= (0<<PORTD3);
}
```

program inside a while(1){..} loop.

At least on my compiler the processor freezes in an infinite loop when it "returns" from main() so it would only execute once after reset. Also you probably should  set the F_CPU to the right number for the Uno if you want the delays to be accurate.